# Equivalent of Force Indicator Within Ta-lib

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, python, indicator

Is there any equivalent of the `Force` indicator (http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:force_index) within the talib library? (http://ta-lib.org/function.html)?